# I've uninstalled FFMpeg, but it still exists when I type "ff" + Tab in terminal window

Tags: linux, macos, ffmpeg

```
➜  ~ brew uninstall ffmpeg
Uninstalling /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4.1... (276 files, 48.2MB)

➜  ~ ffmpeg 
ffmpeg:55: command not found: .mp4

➜  ~ which ffmpeg 
ffmpeg () {
    .mp4
}

➜  ~ whereis ffmpeg 
ffmpeg:

➜  ~
```

So, where is it? How to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### So, where is it? How to remove this?

```
➜  ~ which ffmpeg 
ffmpeg () {
    .mp4
}
```

You have created a `bash` or `zsh` function called `ffmpeg`.

See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/) for a list of locations to check for the definition.

Edit the appropriate file to remove it and restart your terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer! But it seems wasn't me who created that function. It must be a virus or a bug that caused the annoying function. After I restart my computer, it was gone.

Comment: Perhaps `ffmpeg` created it and removed it when you installed it but required a reboot to completely remove it?

Comment: Yes, it may be one possibility.